Updating RDS Instance from Snapshot in Different AWS Account using CloudFormation Nested Stack
I have a CloudFormation nested stack in Account A that creates various resources including an RDS instance from a snapshot (Aurora Serverless). Let's call this snapshot "snapshotA". Now, all these resources are provisioned in Account A.
However, I also have a snapshot in Account B, let's name it "snapshotB", and I want to update the RDS instance created in Account A using this snapshotB without provisioning a new RDS instance.
Is it possible to achieve this using CloudFormation? If not, what would be the best solution?
Aurora Cloudformation Template part:
AuroraDBCluster:
Type: 'AWS::CloudFormation::Stack'
Properties:
  TemplateURL: !Sub 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/${Project}-${Environment}-templates/${Environment}/aurora-snapshot.yaml'
  Parameters:
    Environment: !Sub ${Environment}
    AuroraDBName: X
    VpcId: !GetAtt [CommonVPC, Outputs.VPC]
    PrivateSubnet1Id: !GetAtt [CommonVPC, Outputs.PrivateSubnet1]
    PrivateSubnet2Id: !GetAtt [CommonVPC, Outputs.PrivateSubnet2]
    AuroraDBSecurityGroup: !GetAtt [SecurityGroups, Outputs.AuroraSecurityGroup]
    AuroraClusterSnapshotARN: !Sub ${AuroraClusterSnapshotARN}


What do you mean by "update the RDS instance"?

@jarmod I mean I want to restore my existing RDS instance from another new snapshot.

That seems like an inappropriate thing to try to do in a CloudFormation stack. You have to indicate the snapshot at RDS instance creation time. I'm not aware of another way to do (outside of some custom resource).

@jarmod okay. So in this case creating the new rds instance would change the endpoint of rds instance. Is that something we can avoid ? I don't want to change my rds instance endpoint.

There may be, but I'm not aware of how to avoid the creation of a new endpoint. Ideally, going forward, you would be using a DNS CNAME for your database so the actual endpoint name would not be required on any client.
